# Unable to Migrate/Seed Database - Postgres Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Very odd problem

I am trying to migrate my database but I keep getting:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

Here is my migration:

```
class AddRoleToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :role_id, :integer
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :role_id
  end
end
```

And my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140205191602) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "horseraces", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "horse_id"
    t.integer  "race_id"
    t.datetime "entered"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "horses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "gender"
    t.date     "DOB"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "races", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "race_number"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "roles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "phone_number"
    t.string   "email",                  default: ""
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "role_id"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

I have been trying:

```
rake db:reset
```

and

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

And I get met with the same errors each time.

Interesting that this was working, meaning I had run these commands and got it working. I simply tried to just start fresh and now it's throwing these errors.

Worth noting - I did change a model file from users.rb to user.rb & roles.rb to role.rb I don't know if this would effect anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your config/database.yml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should load the schema first then migrate:

```
rake db:schema:load
rale db:migrate
```

The first command will run your schema.rb file and create the users table. The 2nd will then run your migration and it shouldn't fail because now the users table exists.

Comment: Thank you Diego, that worked perfectly. Weird situation though!

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing often happens when you go back and edit your migrations... might not be exactly what went wrong for you - but it's the first thing that I'd suspect. My strongest suspicion would be that you somehow deleted your "create_users" migration.